# How Can I Share A Single PHPMyAdmin Install Between Two Local Computers?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, mamp

I've installed MAMP on two macs, the MAMP versions are the same and the macs are running the same OS. I've set the document root on both MAMP installations to a location on an office server. I've pasted a basic WP install onto the office server and from both macs when typing 'localhost' I can see the directory fine. When I clicking the WP install on the first mac I can see the basic twenty Seventeen theme fine, however on the second mac all I get is "error establishing database connection".

I can see that the second mac is accessing a different PHPMYADMIN, so my question is how can I link the first macs PHPMYADMIN to the second mac like I've done with the WP installation files?